# Very Low Accuracy on ResNet-50

Tags: tensorflow, transfer-learning, resnet

I'm using transfer learning like resnet50 to classify images using the new version of Fruits360 data set which contained about 6K images in the training set, 24 classes, yet the accuracy recorded is very very low, it does not go above 0.07 with 50 epochs.

I tried the same data with CNN model and VGG16 and it worked just file, only the validation Accuracy is a bit  higher than the training accuracy.

I'm using TensorFlow

Soft-max activation function and Categorical Cross entropy loss

I tried to change from average pooling to max pooling, adding more neurons in flatten layer, adding an extra flatten layer, different dropout rates and nothing has changed

I also tried to load the checkpoints of the model and removing them

something is missing I don't know what is it

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.resnet.ResNet50(
   input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3),
   include_top=False,
   weights='imagenet'
)


base_model.trainable = False

dropout_rate=0.2
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(model)
model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="gap"))
if dropout_rate > 0:
    model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_rate, name="dropout_out"))
model.add(layers.Dense(24, activation='softmax', name="fc_out"))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['Accuracy','Precision','Recall','AUC'])

hist=model.fit(train_generator,
                         epochs = epochs,
                         steps_per_epoch=97,
                         validation_data = test_generator,
                         validation_steps=48
                         
                         )
```

Comment: Without code we can't help you.

Comment: What is your pre-processing? Do you need to scale/transform/one-hot encode the data? Please provide your full code. Model looks fine so far. You could go with a higher lerning rate if you only train the top, but this should not explain the accuracy issue.